# javascript function is not called

Tags: javascript, html

Hello every one I am new to html5 and I have written a small code which I am displaying two rectangle on my canvas using java script but dont know where I am doing wrong as my rectagles are not displayed on my canvas can any one guide me here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<style>
#div2
{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}

</style>

<body>

<div id= "div2">
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="150"></canvas> 

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function init() {
     var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";  
        ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);  

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";  
        ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);}

init();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/YEErC/

Comment: You must try it with a recent browser (so, not IE<9)

Answer (score 0):

```
function init() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";  
        ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);  

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5)";  
        ctx.fillRect (30, 30, 55, 50);}

init();
```

Comment: Assign your canvas element to a variable

Comment: you forgot to add the following code in your function
 
`var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are calling your script before the page load.

Try this:

```
window.onload = init;
```

Also you should try to call init() from Firebug, after page is fully loaded. It works for me.

Answer (score -1):

What browser & version are you using? In the meanwhile you can try the following:

Try moving your script to the `<head></head>` section of your code and then add the `onload` attribute to the `<body>` tag, like so:

```
<body onload="init()">
```

Comment: Even if your syntax was correct (`init()`!), that wouldn't help.

Comment: @Quentin, you're right. I missed the `init()` call at the bottom of OP's script. I still believe my answer provides a better solution as to placing javascript inside the `<body>`, and also an alternative implementation that could indirectly solve any undiscovered problem of OP's implementation by discarding it.

Comment: Putting scripts immediately before `</body>` is a very common pattern to ensure that the script runs after all the elements in the DOM are available without waiting for images to load or allowing the script to block loading of content.

Comment: @Quentin I know that, the point was to provide an alternate working solution.